# Animated SVG + Beamer

Tags: beamer, svg

Good evening.

I recently discovered that it is possible to make some animations quite easily with the SVG format (using SMIL).

Now that I have my animated picture, I would like to use it in a Beamer presentation.

As my previous animations were simple, I just took some pictures that I animated with the animategraphics package, but my current animation is far more complex and I cannot use that solution.

My question is, is there a way to use animated SVGs in a Beamer presentation, or does someone know how I could manage to convert my file to an adequate format ?

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct support for animated SVG in PDF.

You have two options:

1. Convert the SVG into a sequence of vector graphics files in a format suitable for inclusion with LaTeX (PDF or EPS) and animate the sequence using the `\animategraphics` command of the `animate` package.
2. Convert the SVG to SWF and embed it using the `media9` package.